# Named instance and alias not working

Tags: sql-server

I've recently installed SQL Server 2016 on a MacBook Pro via Windows 10 Pro on Parallels.

I set up a named instance and for arguments sake, let's call it `abc\xyz`.

The codebase in at work we use "." for the connection, so means the devs don't constantly have to change the connection. So I thought I'd created an alias called `.` to counter me having to change connections and perhaps checking these in by mistake.

But this hasn't worked. Set in up in 32/64 bit. Used TCP and port 1433, but when I try to connect via SSMS, I get the following error:

> The server was not found or not accessible. Error No 1225.

So could this be down to my setup (Mac OS, Parallels) or my installation? Is the only option to uninstall? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the SQL Server service running?

Comment: Yes I can connect via ssms using the "abc\xyz"

Comment: `.` is built into the client tools as a shortcut for the default instance on the local machine. I doubt you can override it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I had to uninstall and re-install without a named service.  Worked as it was just on my Laptop and a Deve environment, but not ideal it it was a server.

I'd be interested to hear if anyone can get this working without uninstalling.